# Pass collection into custom angular schematic?

Tags: angular-schematics

I want to create a custom angular schematic that can accept a collection of action names.  I will then generate 3 ngrx actions for every action name provided from the user.

for example I want to create a schematic that can be invoked like this:

```
ng g my-collection:my-schematic --actions=GetById,GetByFirstName
```

Then I'll generate code for GetById, GetByIdSuccess, GetByIdError, GetByFirstName, GetByFirstNameSuccess, GetByFirstNameError.

The issue is I've only seen angular schematics that will accept a single value as an input parameter.  Anyone know how to handle collections in a custom angular schematic?

Answer (score 0):

you can follow this blog, it will teach you how to create your own schematics project:

https://blog.angular.io/schematics-an-introduction-dc1dfbc2a2b2

after you generate your schematics project in file `collection.json` you can extend the `@ngrx/schematics`:

```
{
...
"extends": ["@ngrx/schematics"],
}
```

and then use the ngrx schematics to generate 3 actions like this:

```
externalSchematic('@ngrx/schematics', 'action')
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a good example of how to an array of string into a schematic parameter, but I found a workaround.  What I did was have a simple string input parameter that is consistently delimited (I used , to delimit the values).  Here is my schema:

```
export interface Schema {
  name: string;
  path?: string;
  project?: string;
  spec?: boolean;
  actions: string;
  __actions: string[];
  store?: string;
}
```

I parse the actions param that is provided and generate the string array __actions and use that property in my templates.  Here is a snippet from my index.ts:

```
export default function(options: ActionOptions): Rule {
  return (host: Tree, context: SchematicContext) => {
    options.path = getProjectPath(host, options);

    const parsedPath = parseName(options.path, options.name);
    options.name = parsedPath.name;
    options.path = parsedPath.path;
    options.__actions = options.actions.split(',');
    options.__actions = options.__actions.map(_a => classify(_a));
```

If you know of a better way to process these please share.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `actions` multiple times.

```
ng g my-collection:my-schematic --actions=GetById --actions=GetByFirstName
```

Define the parameter as an array within your `schema.json` file.

```
    ...
    "actions": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "description": "The name of the actions."
    },
    ...
```

Also in your `schema.ts`.

```
export interface Schema {
  actions: string[]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pull them right off of the command args, you can do the following:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
  "$id": "Sample",
  "title": "Sample Schematic",
  "type": "object",
  "description": "Does stuff.",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "properties": {
    "things": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "$default": {
        "$source": "argv"
      },
      "description": "Things from the command-line args."
    }
  }
}
```

Then when you run your schematic you can do:

```
schematics schematic-lib:sample stuff other-stuff more-stuff
```

In this case, the `things` property will be `['stuff', 'other-stuff', 'more-stuff']`.

Edit: Note that the `required` value in the schema won't cause the schematic to fail if you don't provide any args. You'd need to do validation on that property in your schematic.